# Integer priority queue with distribution-sensitive deleteMin

Tags: ds.data-structures

Is there in an integer priority queue that uses $O(n)$ words of space with the following operations, all in worst-case time and without access to randomness:

- `createEmptyQueue` in $O(lg^c U)$ for some constant $c$.
- `insert` in $O(1)$.
- `deleteMin` in $O(\delta_{\min})$, where $\delta_{\min}$ is the difference between the smallest and the second-smallest key.

Furthermore, once a key $k$ has been subject to a `deleteMin`, all further inserts are $> k$.

Related work:

[Bose et al.'s "Fast Local Searches and Updates in Bounded Universes"](http://www.cs.umanitoba.ca/~cccg2010/electronicProceedings/paper33.pdf), which is faster than I need for `deleteMin` but slower than I need for `insert`.

[Brodnik et al.'s "Worst case constant time priority queue"](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.28.7131&rep=rep1&type=pdf), which uses the exotic "Yggdrasil memory". For the purposes of this question, I'm interested in more standard integer RAM models.

[Brodnik and Karlsson's "Multiprocess Time Queue"](http://www.imfm.si/preprinti/PDF/00771.pdf), which limits insert to elements with keys in $(k_{\min}, k_{\min} + \delta_{\min}]$, where $k_{\min}$ is the value of the minimum key.

Note that this is pretty simple with a hash table, but that uses amortization and randomness:

- Queues are pairs of a hash table of keys and a copy of the minimum key.
- `insert` adds the key to the hash table and updates the minimum key copy if appropriate.
- `deleteMin` looks up the minimum key in the hash table, then searches for the next minimum key by searching for $k_{\min} + 1, k_{\min} +2, k_{\min} + 3, \dots$ in order.

Answer (score 1):

This paper[1] additionally introduced the "time-finger" property, a unified property encapsulating both the working-set and the queueish properties:

> We present a priority queue that supports the operations: insert in worst-case constant time, and delete, delete-min, find-min and decrease-key on an element $x$ in worst-case $O(lg(min\{w_x,q_x\}+2))$ time, where $w_x$ (respectively, $q_x$) is the number of elements that were accessed after (respectively, before) the last access of $x$ and are still in the priority queue at the time when the corresponding operation is performed.

[1] A. Elmasry, A. Farzan, and J. Iacono, ‘A Unifying Property for Distribution-Sensitive Priority Queues’, in Combinatorial Algorithms, vol. 7056, C. Iliopoulos and W. Smyth, Eds. Springer Berlin Heidelberg, 2011, pp. 209–222.

Comment: This does not answer the question. I am asking for operations that take time proportional to the distance from the smallest to the second smallest key. This measure is incomparable with a measure based $w_x$ and $q_x$.

Comment: Technically it is dependent on those variables; meaning that the deleteMin is distribution sensitive, right?

Comment: $w_x$ and $q_x$ can vary independently of $\delta_{\textrm{min}}$.